# swift add subview to extension UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I try to add a customised UIView onto the UIImageView extension with a customised function.

https://github.com/kentya6/KYCircularProgress

However, i can't see the view's been added. any ideas?

```
import UIKit

public extension UIImageView {

  internal var progressView:KYCircularProgress{
     var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
     return KYCircularProgress(frame: frame)
    }


   public func addProgressView(){
   progressView.progress=0.5
   self.addSubview(progressView)
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely be wanting to use `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame` when initialising your progress view, since the progress view's frame is relative to its superview.

Comment: var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200); even i tried to do the custom frame, it won't show up

Comment: Are you able to post the code where you actually add the progress view? Also, have you considered creating a `UIImageView` subclass and add your progress view at init?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3, try this...

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage
import KYCircularProgress

extension UIImageView {

  func ex_setImage(urlString: String) {

    let status: KYCircularProgress = configureCircularProgress

    let imgManager = ImageViewManager.instance
    if let imgCached = imgManager.imageCache.image(withIdentifier: urlString) {
      self.image = imgCached
      status.isHidden = true
    } else {
      self.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string:urlString)!
        , placeholderImage: nil
        , filter: nil
        , progress: { (progress) in
          status.progress = progress.fractionCompleted
      }, progressQueue: DispatchQueue.main
        , imageTransition: UIImageView.ImageTransition.crossDissolve(2)
        , runImageTransitionIfCached: true
        , completion: { (response) in
          guard let img = response.result.value else { return }
          self.image = img
          imgManager.imageCache.add(img, withIdentifier: urlString)
      })
    }

  }

  internal var configureCircularProgress: KYCircularProgress {
    let cgreact = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    let statusProgress = KYCircularProgress(frame: cgreact)
    statusProgress.isHidden = false
    statusProgress.colors = [UIColor(rgba: 0xA6E39D11), UIColor(rgba: 0xAEC1E355), UIColor(rgba: 0xAEC1E3AA), UIColor(rgba: 0xF3C0ABFF)]
    statusProgress.guideLineWidth = 1.0
    statusProgress.showGuide = true
    statusProgress.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    statusProgress.progress = 0.001
    statusProgress.progressChanged { (progress, circularProgress) in
      print("^^^^^ progress: \(progress)")
      circularProgress.isHidden = progress == 1.0
    }
    self.addSubview(statusProgress)
    return statusProgress
  }

}


class ImageViewManager {

  public static var instance = ImageViewManager()

  public let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
    memoryCapacity: UInt64(100).megabytes(),
    preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: UInt64(60).megabytes()
  )

}
```